# Thai DateTime conversion issue in .net

Tags: asp.net, datetime, multilingual, cultureinfo

I have a ASP.net MVC3 application which is being used in different countries in their local languages. We use cultureinfo settings to set the culture for particular country. 
In Thailand the culture setting is

```
<globalization culture="th-th" uiCulture="th-th"/>
```

Now when user selects date from Jquery calender in form and submits the form dates gets converted while saving into DB. E.g. if user selects 2012-02-03 gets converted into 1469-02-03 .

Any idea why this is happening and what is the best way to store the date in multilingual sites?

Answer (score 0):

Thailand use Buddhist Era which equal Christian Era plus 543 years, so if user want to select the year 2012 in Buddhist Era user have to select it 2555.